# Neo4j Cypher get all nodes in a linked list

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

With the following graph:

(Boxer)-[:starts]->(Round)-[:continues]->(Round)-[:continues]->(Round)-[:continues]->(Round)

How can I get all the rounds done by a specific boxer?

Right now, I'm only able to get ALL the rounds from ALL the boxers with this:
(And i miss the first rounds because the first relationship is STARTS and not CONTINUES.

```
MATCH (boxer:Boxer {id: 5})
MATCH ()-[:continues]->(round:Round)
 RETURN
  boxer {
   .*,
   rounds: collect(distinct round {
    .*
   })
  } as boxer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH p = (boxer:Boxer)-[:starts]->()-[:continues*0..]->(lastRound)
WHERE boxer.id = 5 AND NOT (lastRound)-[:continues]->()
RETURN boxer {
   .*,
   rounds: NODES(p)[1..]
  } as boxer
```

- The [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern `[:continues*0..]` uses `0` as the lower bound, in case a bout only has one round.
- The `NOT (lastRound)-[:continues]->()` test filters for the paths that end at a leaf node, so that the `MATCH` only gets the paths of entire bouts.
- The returned `rounds` property should contain all the rounds in a bout.
- This query assumes that the `starts` and `continues` relationship types always have `Round` end nodes, so for efficiency we do not bother to specify those node labels in the `MATCH` pattern.

Comment: Wonderful, that works as expected. Your explanation and doc helps a lot. Thanks.